# Re-write Laravel raw queries using PDO

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, prepared-statement, query-builder

I have a query like this in Laravel:

```
$this
   ->db
   ->selectRaw('SUM(rewards * coef) AS revenue')
```

and

```
$this
   ->db
   ->selectRaw('COUNT(distinct question) * 0.001 AS revenue')
```

How can I re-write these so there will not be any SQL injection possibilities ?

May be using prepared statements ?

Comment: There is no SQL injection danger here because you don't use any variables...

Comment: Your code is already secure against SQL injection. The best you can now achieve is write an exception handler (if laravel doesn't provide one), create a template to show to the user in case the query returned null data etc.